# counting problem - number of possible values

Tags: combinatorics

how many among the first 100,000 positive integers contain exactly one of each $3,4$ and $5$ in their decimal representation?

Do we have to enumerate all starting from $3$ digit then $4$ digit then $5$ digit possibilities

Comment: It's easier to just use $5$ digit numbers, but allow them to begin with $0$. So, for instance, instead of $154$, you write $00154$. That way, you can take care of all $3$, $4$ and $5$ digit numbers simultaneously, plus you don't have to take special care of the first digit.

Comment: Fully agree with @Arthur. Also you can do it for the first $100,000$ nonnegative integers (first: $00000$, last: $99999$). That will not affect the outcome.

Comment: @Arthur : how many different $3$-digit numbers can be formed with $3$ fours,$4$ two's and $2$ three's ? how to go about it ? enumerate all possibility ?

Answer (score 1):

For integers from $0$ to $100000$ you are basically looking for all the permutations with repetition of $10$ elements ($0$ to $9$) when taking $5$ (plus the $100000$, but we don't care about it since it's not one of the numbers we want to count).

Now, though, we want to change it a bit.
Take the digits $3, 4, 5$ (there's only $1$ way to do it).

Take all the possible positions where $3,4,5$ can be, considering where each will be (there's $5\times 4\times 3=60$ ways to do so).

For the remaining $2$ positions, make all possible permutations with repetition of $7$ elements (there are $7^2=49$)

So, our counting is $1\times 60\times 49=2940$